# Property null after adding to MVC base model in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

this is an issue that has been happening for a couple of weeks now, was wondering if anyone has encountered this , and if there is a fix :

Say I have a View Model called 'ListFruitsViewModel' , which for the sake of argument contains a base model of 'Fruit' that has the properties

```
public Guid fruitID {get; set;}

public String fruitName {get; set;}
```

ok so I go ahead and create the ListFruits view , perform some action and all works ok.

but then I realise I need to change the 'Fruit' model to include a 'fruitColor' property. So I change the properties of 'Fruit' to look like :

```
public Guid fruitID {get; set;}

public String fruitName {get; set;}

public String fruitColor {get; set;}
```

now I can see the fruitColor property in the Razor intellisense etc, I ve changed the method that populates the fruits in the list to include the new property etc, and no matter what I try, the fruitColor property is always null in the View Model.

Its almost like although VS knows there is a new property, the underlying assembly files have not picked up that there is a new property in the 'Fruit' model, and is not populating it.

Various combinations of cleans / builds / rebuilds have not fixed the issue, and a VS restart holds no joy.

I am certain this is a quirk of VS and the way it updates complied code.
Any ideas?

EDIT: one real-world example then :

I have a class of type report with Properties:

```
    public Guid reportID { get; set; }
    public String reportName { get; set; }
    public DateTime reportCreated { get; set; }
    public String reportCreatedBy { get; set; }

    and I have just added:

    public String reportCode { get; set; }
```

Im bringing in a list of these back from a database so Ive changed the method that populates the list to :

```
public List<Report> ListReports() {
            List<Report> list = new List<Report>();
            DAL.DAL dal = new DAL.DAL();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Report item;
            dt = dal.ListAllReports();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
              item = new Report() {
              reportID = new Guid(row["ReportID"].ToString()), 
              reportName = row["ReportName"].ToString(), 
              reportCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(row["ReportCreatedDateTime"].ToString()), 
                reportCreatedBy = row["ReportCreatedBy"].ToString(),
                reportCode = row["ReportCode"].ToString()
                };
                list.Add(item);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

I can step through the ListReports() method , and can see the values are being passed in to the object at this point, but the property is always null in the View Model, while the other properties are populated as expected.

Comment: Just for completeness, can we have a look at the code that populates the fruit list, including this new property? And the view which uses it, for that matter?

Comment: Hi Andrei, this is a theoretical example as it has been happening to various projects, ill try and get an example I can post on here

Comment: Then we possibly need a real case scenario to figure this one out. It should not, and does not, happen usually - it never happened to me, for example. So there must be something specific yet common for all your cases

Comment: Code looks fine. Do you run this on IIS or on VS development server?

Comment: This is just running on localhost in VS, I have found that renaming all the instances of the modified class seems to fix it, so the new property is populated, but I don't want to have to do that every time I add a property. I just wondered if anyone else has seen this before?

Comment: Are these classes defined in the same assembly? If not, do you use project references?

Comment: Hi Rowland, all of the examples I have had this happen are instances of base classes within the same project.